# drjava: Is closing upon cancelling intended?

Tags: java, save, drjava

Whenever I try to close a file in drjava after making some edits and not saving, the program, as expected, gives the dialog box:
"[Filename] has been modified. Would you like to save it?"

In many cases, I'll decide at this point to cancel the closing and make some more edits, then save the file manually.

Unfortunately, hitting "Cancel" has the same effect as hitting "No": the window closes without saving, and I lose my work.

Is this the intended behavior of drjava? Or is there some option to select / some code I can use to fix the problem? Although as long as I remember the behavior it's manageable, it's still pretty inconvenient.

Comment: sounds like awfully written software to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's open source, so we can take a look at the implementation. Here's the code that opens the dialog (some code omitted) [from the newest branch](http://sourceforge.net/p/drjava/code/HEAD/tree/branches/drjava-hj/drjava/src/edu/rice/cs/drjava/ui/MainFrame.java#l9951):

```
private boolean _fileSaveHelper(OpenDefinitionsDocument doc, int paneOption) {
  ...

  int rc = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(MainFrame.this, text, "Save " + fname + "?", paneOption);
  switch (rc) {
    case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
      boolean saved = false;
      if (notFound) saved = _saveAs(); 
      else saved = _save();
      if (doc != lastActive) {
        _model.setActiveDocument(lastActive);  // breaks when "if" clause omitted
      }
      return saved;
    case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
      if (doc != lastActive) {
      _model.setActiveDocument(lastActive);  // breaks when "if" clause omitted
    }
      return true;
    case JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION:
    case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
      return false;
    default:                         // never executed
      throw new RuntimeException("Invalid option: " + rc);
  }
}
```

There are separate cases for "no" and "cancel", so it looks like they do try to handle it properly. Thus it's probably a bug. The method is referenced by this method

```
public boolean quitFile(OpenDefinitionsDocument doc) { 
  return _fileSaveHelper(doc, JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION); 
}
```

which is referenced somewhere outside MainFrame.java. I am not inclined to look into it as I don't even have a Java IDE installed. If you wish, you can fork the project and use an IDE like Eclipse to quickly find the references to the method. Speaking of which, I'd suggest just using Eclipse as I remember Dr. Java offering little in the way of basic features such as code completion and formatting.